# Python Euler Integration Method for two body system not producing correct plot

Tags: python, numpy, overflow, integration

I have been attempting to get a two body problem to work, which in the future should be used for more planets, but it is not working and the plot I am supposed to get is circular but I am receiving a straight line for the two body systems. Does anyone know how I can fix this and get the correct plot?

This is the code I use:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

aEarth = 1 #semi-major axis (AU)
eEarth = 0.0167 #eccentricity (no units)

aMercury = 0.387098 #semi-major axis (AU)
eMercury = 0.205635 #eccentricity (no units)
    
Msun = 1 #Mass of Sun (Solar Mass)
Mearth = 3.0024584*10**(-6) #Mass of Earth (Solar Mass)
Mmercury = 1.65956463*10**(-7) #Mass of Mercury (Solar Mass)
Mes = (Msun + Mearth)
Mms = (Msun + Mmercury)
G = 1 #Gravitational Constant 

apocentreEarth = (aEarth*(1 + eEarth))
apocentreMercury = (aMercury*(1 + eMercury))

vapocentreEarth = (np.sqrt((G*(Mearth+Msun)/aEarth)*((1-eEarth)/(1+eEarth))))
vapocentreMercury = (np.sqrt((G*(Mmercury+Msun)/aMercury)*(1-eMercury/1+eMercury)))

xEarth = apocentreEarth
yEarth = 0.0
zEarth = 0.0

vxEarth = 0.0
vyEarth =(vapocentreEarth)
vzEarth = 0.0

xMercury = apocentreMercury
yMercury = 0.0
zMercury = 0.0

vxMercury = 0.0
vyMercury =(vapocentreMercury)
vzMercury = 0.0

class CelBody(object):
    # Constants of nature
    def __init__(self, id, name, x0, v0, mass, color, lw):
        # Name of the body (string)
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        # Mass of the body (solar mass)
        self.M = mass
        # Initial position of the body (au)
        self.x0 = np.asarray(x0, dtype=float)
        # Position (au). Set to initial value.
        self.x = self.x0.copy()
        # Initial velocity of the body (au/s)
        self.v0 = np.asarray(v0, dtype=float)
        # Velocity (au/s). Set to initial value.
        self.v = self.v0.copy()
        self.a = np.zeros([3], dtype=float)
        self.color = color
        self.lw = lw

# All Celestial Objects

t = 0
dt = 0.01

Bodies = [
    CelBody(0, 'Sun', [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], Msun, 'yellow', 10),
    CelBody(1, 'Earth', [xEarth, yEarth, zEarth], [vxEarth, vyEarth, vzEarth], Mearth, 'blue', 3),
    CelBody(2, 'Mercury', [xMercury, yMercury, zMercury], [ vxMercury, vyMercury, vzMercury], Mmercury, 'pink', 3),
    ]

paths = [ [ b.x[:2].copy() ] for b in Bodies]

# loop over ten astronomical years
v = 0
for t in range(0,1000):
    # compute forces/accelerations
    for body in Bodies:
        body.a *= 0
        for other in Bodies:
            # no force on itself
            if (body == other): continue # jump to next loop
            rx = body.x - other.x
            r3 = (np.sqrt(rx[0]**2+rx[1]**2+rx[2]**2))**3
            body.a = -G*other.M*rx/r3

    for n, planet in enumerate(Bodies):
        # use the Forward Euler algorithm 
        planet.a = -G*other.M*rx/r3
        planet.v = planet.v + planet.a*dt
        planet.x = planet.x + planet.v*dt
        paths[n].append( planet.x[:2].copy() )
        #print("%10s x:%53s v:%53s"%(planet.name,planet.x, planet.v))


plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
for n, planet in enumerate(Bodies): 
    px, py=np.array(paths[n]).T; 
    plt.plot(px, py, color=planet.color, lw=planet.lw)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The fact that you're getting an overflow warning but are not sure where it's coming from indicates to me that you have not yet used a debugger to step through your code line-by-line and inspect the contents of each variable at each point. PyCharm is free and has an excellent debugger. I suggest using it to step through your code, so that you can see exactly when the results start deviating from your expectations. Here is how to use it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in these lines:

```
    planet.v += planet.v + planet.a*dt
    planet.x += planet.x + planet.v*dt
```

They are equivalent to

```
    planet.v = 2*planet.v + planet.a*dt
    planet.x = 2*planet.x + planet.v*dt
```

which is not what you want.

Either don't use `+=`, or change those lines to:

```
    planet.v += planet.a*dt
    planet.x += planet.v*dt
```

There is still a problem: the first line changes `planet.v`, and then the second used the *new* `planet.v` to update `planet.x`, which is not how the explicit Euler integration should proceed.
(There is a comment in the code abou using symplectic Euler, but a comment to this answer says you meant to use forward (i.e. explicit) Euler.)

For this system, a simple fix is to switch the statements:

```
    planet.x += planet.v*dt
    planet.v += planet.a*dt
```

There may be other issues.  If you need more help, please *simplify* the code as much as possible to create a [*minimal* reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  As it is now, it looks like there are quite a few irrelevant variables declared, two different places where you are computing Euler's method, two places where you assign `dt`, three bodies defined when you say you are solving the two body problem, etc.

---

*Edit* After your update, there are a couple bugs left:

- In the loop that begins `for body in Bodies:`, in which you compute `body.a` for each body, the results should be accumulated, so the line that updates `body.a` should be

  ```
              body.a += -G*other.M*rx/r3
  ```

  (note the change to `+=`).
- In second inner loop (`for n, planet in enumerate(Bodies):`), in which you apply the Euler method step, delete the line

  ```
          planet.a = -G*other.M*rx/r3
  ```

  You already computed the accelerations in the previous loop and stored them in `planet.a`.

If I make just those two changes to the code that is now in the question, the plot shows the circular orbits that you expected.

Comment: Thank you for correcting that, I have removed the + but it still isn't producing a circular plot and it is a straight line.

Comment: I added another suggestion, but I just noticed code comment about using the *symplectic* Euler method, so I might have to fix that..

Comment: Sorry that was my bad I wrote the wrong Euler method I was using I am supposed to use the Forward Euler algorithm.

Comment: Could I potentially get some more help I have since simplified the code. Should I still change the statements to     planet.x += planet.v*dt and 
    planet.v += planet.a*dt

Comment: @poboma, see my last update.

Comment: Thank you so much I have implemented the changes and obtained the needed circular plot.